Add sprites with a constant size relative to the model objects
The viewableData.spriteSize defines the  Sprite sizes based on screen pixels. As a result, when we zoom in and zoom out of the model, the sprite sizes change, which can be problematic especially when we zoom out of the model as the sprites become very big compared to model objects.
Is there a way to define sprites with a constant size relative to the model objects?

Hi, please check the answer and let me know if it was helpful

You can scale the sprites based on the zoom level, eg:
viewableData.finish().then(() => {
    this._dataVizExt.addViewables(viewableData);
    this.viewer.addEventListener(Autodesk.Viewing.CAMERA_CHANGE_EVENT, (e) => {
        let spritesToUpdate = this._dataVizExt.viewableData.viewables.map((v) => v.dbId);
        if (e.camera.far > 400) {
            this._dataVizExt.invalidateViewables(spritesToUpdate, (viewable) => {
                return {
                    scale: 0.5, // Reduce the viewable size
                };
            });
        }else{
            this._dataVizExt.invalidateViewables(spritesToUpdate, (viewable) => {
                return {
                    scale: 1, // Keep it to default
                };
            });
        }
    })
});

